# Eclipse: How to get the MenuManager for a specific menu id defined in plugin.xml

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a standalone eclipse RCP application. The main interaction happens through the main toolbar. Here is the relevant snippet from plugin.xml:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
     <toolbar
           id="my.toolbar.id">
        ...
        <command
              commandId="my.command.id"
              id="my.connect.id"
              label="Connect"
              style="pulldown">
        </command>
        ...
     </toolbar>
  </menuContribution>
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="menu:my.connect.id">
  </menuContribution>
```

I would like to populate the pulldown menu `my.connect.id` when it is about to be shown, which can hold different items every time it is opened. It can be done using the `MenuManager` for this id and add a `IMenuListener`.

How to obtain the instance of the `MenuManager` for the given id from plugin.xml?

Thanks a lot.

PS: It is still e3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took me a couple of days and research to figure this out. Here is the answer to my own question:

Give the menu a dyanmic contribution with a class that handles all the contributions.

plugin.xml:

```
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="menu:my.connect.id">
     <dynamic
           class="my.ConnectMenu"
           id="my.connect.menu">
     </dynamic>
  </menuContribution>
```

ConnectMenu.java:

```
public class ConnectMenu extends ContributionItem {

    private IMenuListener menuListener = new IMenuListener() {
        public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
            fillMenu(manager);
        }
    };

    public ConnectMenu() {
        this("my.connect.menu");
    }

    public ConnectMenu(String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void fill(Menu menu, int index) {
        super.fill(menu, index);

        if (getParent() instanceof MenuManager) {
            ((MenuManager) getParent()).setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
            ((MenuManager) getParent()).addMenuListener(menuListener);
        }
    }

    private void fillMenu(IMenuManager mgr) {
        mgr.add(createContributionItem());      

        mgr.update();
    }

    private IContributionItem createContributionItem() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Very helpful to me: https://phisymmetry.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/eclipse-tips-how-to-create-menu-items-dynamically/